# Java nested JPanel is not maintaining the specified size

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, preferredsize

I Have a `JFrame` which has 2 `JPanels` contained within, one of which is 70% of the `JFrame` the other is the remaining 30%. The `JPanel` that is 30% of the width has a nested JPanel within it. However this nested `JPanel` should be 50% of the width its parent JPanel however when it is displayed it takes up the full width of the parent `JPanel`.

The parent `JPanel` is of `width 358` and `height 772`, the nested `JPanel` has the following values: `width 179` and `height 772`

I have set the colours of these components to green and gray, so i can easily see if they are being rendered correctly. When i run my application, the nested `JPanel` is actually being rendered as if it were the full width of the `parent` (the whole area gets rendered green).

This is the code currently.

```
public class DisplayFrame extends JFrame{

    private final static int WIDTH = 1200;
    private final static int HEIGHT = 800;      
    private DisplayCanvas canvas;   
    private ControlContainer controlContainer;

    public DisplayFrame() {    
        //simple inheritance. 
        super(title);
        setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);    
        addComponents(this.getContentPane());    
    } 

    public void addComponents(Container container){
        canvas = DisplayCanvas.getInstance(container);    
        canvas.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        container.add(canvas);          
        controlContainer = ControlContainer.getInstance(container);    
        controlContainer.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
        container.add(controlContainer);
    }    
}
```

The panel with 70% width

```
public class DisplayCanvas extends JPanel{

    private final double WIDTH_PERCENT = 70;    
    private static DisplayCanvas instance;

    private DisplayCanvas(Container parent) {    
        this.setSize(new Dimension(MathHelper.calculateXPercentOfY(WIDTH_PERCENT, 
            parent.getWidth()), parent.getHeight()));
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setVisible(true);    
    }
    //implement the singleton 
    public static DisplayCanvas getInstance(Container parent) {    
        if(instance != null){
            return instance;
        }    
        instance = new DisplayCanvas(parent);    
        return instance;
    }
}
```

the panel with 30% width:

```
public class ControlContainer extends JPanel{

    private final double WIDTH_PERCENT = 30;
    private static ControlContainer instance;
    private ControlPanel controlPanel;

    private ControlContainer(Container parent) {
        this.setSize(new Dimension(MathHelper.calculateXPercentOfY(WIDTH_PERCENT, 
             parent.getWidth()), parent.getHeight()));
        this.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));
        this.setVisible(true);
        addControlElements(this);           
    }

    //implement Singelton
    public static ControlContainer getInstance(Container parent){    
        if(instance != null){
            return instance;
        }    
        instance = new ControlContainer(parent);        
        return instance;    
    }

    public void addControlElements(Container parent){           
        controlPanel = ControlPanel.getInstance(parent);
        controlPanel.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);         
        System.out.println("ControlContainer: " + parent.getWidth() 
             + "       " + parent.getHeight()+ " vis: " + parent.isVisible());
        System.out.println("ControlPanel: " + controlPanel.getWidth() 
             + "       " + controlPanel.getHeight() + " vis: " + controlPanel.isVisible());
        parent.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);                  
    }
}
```

Now, this panel should be nested inside `ControlContainer` with 50% of its width.

```
public class ControlPanel extends JPanel{       

        private final double WIDTH_PERCENT = 50;        
        private static ControlPanel instance;

        private ControlPanel(Container parent) {
            super.setSize(new Dimension(MathHelper.calculateXPercentOfY(WIDTH_PERCENT, 
                  parent.getWidth()), parent.getHeight()));
            super.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            super.setVisible(true);        
        }

        //implement singelton measures
        public static ControlPanel getInstance(Container parent){        
            if(instance != null){
                return instance;
            }        
            instance = new ControlPanel(parent);        
            return instance;        
        }
    }
```

This is the output from the `addControlElements` method:

```
ControlContainer: 358       772 vis: true
ControlPanel: 179       772 vis: true
```

This is used just to test if the values are set as expected, as you can see `ControlPanel` `width is 179` which is what is expected however, when rendered it fills the whole of the `ControlContainer`.

Hopefully you understand what i mean, its not the easiest to explain.

Comment: Your DisplayCanvas is under the control of a layout manager (specifically, a FlowLayout), this means means that when the container is invalidated, the layout manager will resize the components under its control. You can use GridBagLayout to achieve what you are trying to do. DrawCanvas.getInstance isn't exactly a good idea, as a component can't only belong to a single parent and this gives your code the ability to change this components parent without inteventation or control

Comment: @MadProgrammer Does the problem not lie with Control container? DisplayCanvas renders fine. ControlPanel is the problem or am i miss understanding?

Comment: The problem is with your complete idea. It's not the responsibility of the child components to lay themselves out, they provide sizing "hints" tote containers layout manager, which makes decisions about how each component should be laid out. The layout manager is quite well within its rights to ignore these hints based on its own needs (GridLayout for example)

Comment: Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer i can't seem to get it working, could you post it as an answer? when i try both JPanels appear in the middle and are super small. Ive looked at videos and your past answers, still no luck. Maybe if i see it in this context i can see where i went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to understand how components are laied out in Swing.  Take a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) to see how you might be able achieve the result you are looking for

[image: Test]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new BasePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class BasePane extends JPanel {

        public BasePane() {
            TestPane top = new TestPane();
            TestPane bottom = new TestPane();

//          top.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
//          bottom.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 0.3;

            add(top, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.weighty = 0.7;

            add(bottom, gbc);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }


    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            Dimension mySize = getSize();
            Dimension parentSize = getParent().getSize();

            String widthPer = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance().format((float) mySize.width / (float) parentSize.width);
            String heightPer = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance().format((float) mySize.height / (float) parentSize.height);

            String[] text = new String[]{
                "Me = " + mySize.width + "x" + mySize.height,
                "Parent = " + parentSize.height + "x" + parentSize.height,
                "Perctange = " + widthPer + "x" + heightPer
            };

            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int y = (getHeight() - (fm.getHeight() * text.length)) / 2;
            for (String value : text) {
                int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(value)) / 2;
                g2d.drawString(value, x, y + fm.getAscent());
                y += fm.getHeight();
            }

            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you that helped massively, i have a new problem now made a new question as its sort of off topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619238/java-gridbaglayout-seems-to-be-ignoring-component-size